# How to redirect to create action of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, omniauth

I understand that I cannot POST on an HTML redirect, but my situation requires that I redirect to create action after authenticating user. I would like to know how to bypass this restriction:

In particular, I would like to allow an user to fill out a post without logging in using Omniauth. I save the post to session[:post] using an AJAX call. Then, the user can login using omniauth and persist the post.

I have a PostsController with create action that  handle initial ajax call, and also handle html request after authenticating user:

```
  def create    
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])   
    respond_to do |format|    
      format.html{
        if @post.save
          redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
        else
          render action: "new"
        end
      }
      format.json {
        if session[:post] = @post
          render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
        else
          render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in my controller that handles callback from Facebook, I have:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ... authentication logic here ...
    sign_in(:user, service.user)
    redirect_to :controller => "posts", :action =>"create"
  end
  method_alias: :facebook, :create
```

However, this doesn't work, because I can't redirect to a "create" action. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: I think is is `render action => :create`, but I'm struggeling to find the doc for it.

Comment: @Cort3z : I'll greatly appreciate if you could find out. I'll look for it too.

Comment: You should create an answer instead of editing your question, it will be more readable for future visitors. Look at the following url on how to add a `persist` route without the error (use a collection route in your case): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: @Baldrick: thanks a bunch for the tip on collection route. I'll modify my code and add it as an answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Now you can accept your own answer, so it's the first visible answer.

Comment: @Baldrick: Thanks. I have to wait for 2 days after posting the answer, but I will.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, you never read the content of the session. I think it can work if you change your code with this :

Change initialization of `@post`:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post]) || session[:post]  # Find object in session if not
```

And add after `post.save` :

```
session.delete :post   # clean session after successful creation
```

New full method:

```
  def create    
    @post = Post.new(params[:post]) || session[:post]  # Find object in session if not in params  
    respond_to do |format|    
      format.html{
        if @post.save
          redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
          session.delete :post   # clean session after successful creation
        else
          render action: "new"
        end
      }
      format.json {
        if session[:post] = @post
          render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
        else
          render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error. However, the error message I got was caused by the fact that I can't redirect to create action, as it is a POST. I've never had a change to get to #create by HTML request :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method on a Post model and call it both from PostsController and ServicesController to save the post (though in this case it's quite trivial: new, then save, so you achieve nothing in terms of DRY, may be some encapsulation benefits). Or create a common mixin containing the create_post method with all the logic. Then and include it into SessionsController and PostsController and call it from 'create'.

In the mixin module:

```
def create_post(allow_json=false)
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])   
  respond_to do |format|    
    format.html {
      if @post.save
        redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
      else
        render "posts/new"
      end
    }
    if allow_json
      ... your post-saving & json-processing logic ...
    end
  end
end
```

In PostsController:

```
def create
  create_post(true)
end
```

In SessionsController:

```
def create
  ... authentication logic here ...
  sign_in(:user, service.user)
  create_post(false)
end
```

I didn't compile and try, so I only hope it works. In general, I must say there's something basically wrong, so I'd look for other architectural solutions to achieve the same results, but as a quick-and-dirty approach it should probably work.

Comment: @Cort3z I beieve the point is not in displaying the view what you can do through render (render "posts/new" as I believe here "posts/create" is a POST request and doesn't have a view) but actually creating the post (it was only stored in session, not created in db in format.json block originally). So, render is not what you need. redirect_to, well, can't redirect to POST requests, so you end up doing something with your architecture to achieve the same result.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Creating a module to share a method between two controllers is a new learning to me. However, this probably shows that there's something fundamentally wrong here :). I come up with another solution that can avoid calling a method from two controllers like the first approach you suggested (see my update).

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack to avoid this issue: I let #create handling AJAX call and write to session, then create another action to persist it into my database after user get authenticated:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create  
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        if session[:post] = @post
          render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
        else
          render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      }
    end
  end

  def persist
    @post = session[:post]
    if @post.save
       session.delete :post
       redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
     else
       render action: "new"
     end
  end
```

Then in my routes.rb, I have:

```
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      get 'persist'
    end
  end
```

Finally, in my ServicesController:

```
sign_in(:user, service.user) 
redirect_to persist_posts_path
```